# Crossing Austria by sleeper train without getting off - do Austrian covid entry rules apply?

Tags: transit, trains, covid-19, borders

I will soon take the sleeper train from Zurich to Ljubljana.

The train route covers Switzerland-Austria-Slovenia. I will not be getting off until my final destination. As of today (May 2022), Slovenia lifted the requirement to show proof of test, recovery or vaccination. Austria still has it AFAIK. Information regarding transiting passengers in such situation is difficult to find.

Do I need to abide by the Austrian rules even if I remain on board the train for the whole crossing of the country?

Comment: You will probably not be asked to show anything. I wasn't a few weeks ago. But make sure you do have your vaccination certificate with you.

Answer (score 11):

The rules state, according to the [Austrian Embassy in Washington](https://www.austria.org/current-travel-information):

> Persons entering Austria for the following purposes are not subject to COVID-19 entry restrictions or mandatory quarantine:
>
> - TRANSIT through Austria without stop or unnecessary delay. A change in mode of transportation is admissible (e.g. plane to train, bus, taxi, etc.).
> - ...

Similar information can be found in the German FAQ of the [Bundesministerium für Soziales, Gesundheit, Pflege und Konsumentenschutz](https://www.sozialministerium.at/Informationen-zum-Coronavirus/Coronavirus---Haeufig-gestellte-Fragen/FAQ-Einreise-nach-Oesterreich.html):

> Folgende Personengruppen sind bei der Ein- und Wiedereinreise von der COVID-19-Einreiseverordnung ausgenommen:
>
> - ...
> - Transitpassagiere bzw. Personen, die ohne Zwischenstopp durch Österreich durchreisen,
> - ...

The German Automobile Club ADAC [notes](https://www.adac.de/news/oesterreich-urlaub-corona/#transit-durch-oesterreich) that they usually tolerate short stops for buying gas or going to the toilet.

Comment: Seriously? So they figure spending several _hours_ in a closed space with people getting on and off the train is not a danger for contagion? That seems completely insane, are you sure? An infectious person on a busy train could infect several dozen other passengers, especially if various people get on and off during the journey. Are you really sure this applies to someone crossing the country by train?

Comment: @terdon: Yes. COVID legislation around here is highly political and, as a result, highly illogical. The virus will surely not propagate on the Swiss or Slovenian part of the journey.

Comment: @terdon You are trying to use logic and science? Sorry politicians don't do that.